# Mail template send to distributor

Tags: expresso-store

My client uses Store for an online shop. Once the products are ordered online and paid for she wants an email to be sent to the distributor who is taking care of order picking, packaging and shipping. That mail should than contain the necessary order and shipping info. But should not be sent to the customer.

Will that be possible within Store?

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many different email templates as you like when orders are placed. So you could create separate ones for admin, customer and distributor.

Comment: Got that. The issue though is that each template is also sent to the customers mail address! You don't want the distributors instructions ending up at the customers desk.

Comment: Sorry, been a while since I worked with Store, and it seems I didn't look closely enough. Yeah, you can't specify who to send the emails to, and it looks like what you want is on their feature requests list: https://exp-resso.com/store/support